# Azure B2C single sign On Doesn't work

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have two applications that are running on my localhost @ port 6420 and 6421. Both the Appications are using MSAL to login.
Both the applications are registered on AZURE B2C.

I successfully logged in to the application running on port 6420. But when i now try to browse the application running on 6421, it prompts me again for username/password.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Have you done the configuration described here: [Single sign-on (SSO) configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#single-sign-on-sso-configuration)

Comment: Yes, I have done that and set that to Tenant

Comment: Is there any code you can share to show your authentication request? Is it possible that you are passing "prompt=login"?

Comment: We are using MSAL library to authenticate. 
is there something in the code that needs to be added to get it working as SSO.

Comment: Is there a parameter called `prompt` when users was redirected to the login page? eg. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxi.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_Sign_In&client_id={clientId}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login`

Comment: This is not resolved yet.
I see prompt=select_account

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage the SSO function, we shouldn't pass the `prompt` parameter with value `select_account`. Please check the code to see whether you add this parameter and remove it.

In-addition, I tested the code sample [active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) and which the request is without `prompt` parameter and works well.

Comment: But that is something generated automatically when we redirect to azure login page. What change do i need to do , so that the url is generated without prompt